# Как создать собственный status bar?

Tags: android

Почему-то когда я задаю такой вопрос, то люди начинают минусовать вопрос, причем не только на stackoverflow. Отчего люди минусуют этот вопрос? Я не могу найти ничего, кроме [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829309/how-to-create-a-custom-status-bar-in-android-common-for-all-activity-in-android): никаких туториалов, никаких проектов на github. Некоторые говорят, что это невозможно, хотя у меня приложение от HTC - "В машине", там есть свой собственный status bar, также существует масса приложений: super status bar, material status bar, omega statusbar - все они изменяют status bar на android 4.2.2. И так:

1. Почему люди минусуют вопрос? (Я могу объяснить это явление только как неумение мною гуглить, хотя я уже второй месяц этим занимаюсь и пока безуспешно.)
2. Есть ли какие-нибудь туториалы, либо готовые проекты? Я лично ничего не могу найти, перепробовал все варианты формулировки вопроса.

Comment: Вам StatusBar только для своего приложения или Вы хотите подменить системный?

Comment: @kff Только для своего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос. Создать кастомный status bar нельзя. Этим могут заниматься лишь определенные разработчики (компании). Но можно вывести информацию о статусе сети, wi-fi, батареи и GPS.

Answer (score 1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Теперь ваше приложение на весь экран развёрнуто. Делаете LinearLayout и размещаете его в самом верху слоя - кастомный status bar готов.

Осталось "только" теперь самому реализовать всё то, что есть в стандартном status bar'е.